# Can String.Split() ever return null? (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, string

Does `System.String.Split()` ever return `null`? (.NET)

I know I've been coding in the belief that it does not, however, upon reading the docs I do not see such a statement. Since there is no such a statement in the docs, so I want to ask in the experience of the community has anyone actually encountered the case that `string.Split` returns `null`?

Comment: Think about what Split does. The answer is right in front of you.

Comment: Yeah, In retrospect it should have been obvious. Oh well, too late to un-ask it now. :)

Comment: @asawyer 5 years later, I am curios how is the answer right in front of him?

Comment: @eaglei22 Split means to break into n parts, n is always an integer, integers are never null.  I would expect an exception to be thrown in most cases rather then a null returned and in the case of calling split on a null string that is in fact what happens. The fact that it returns a mutable array that itself can be null is a hold-over from pre .Net 2.0 generics time. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/

Comment: @eaglei22 For someone to Comment about how "_The answer is right in front of you._", and then _not_ give the answer is just trolling.  This is not a dumb question.  If it was, then I guess we're all dumb for landing on this page and upvoting.  Note: If your String is `null`, then it _will_ throw an Exception (like it would for calling any Method on a `null` Object).  If no Delimiter is found to Split, then you end up with an Array of 1 Value - the Value of the whole String (which can _never_ be `null`).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, it cannot return null. If you look at the source of it, it even guarantees it with code contracts:

```
public String[] Split(params char[] separator) {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String[]>() != null);
```

All public overloads also make the same guarantee.

Answer (score 28):

No, it doesn't return null. If the separator is not present, it returns the whole string

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

> If this instance does not contain any of the strings in separator, the returned array consists of a single element that contains this instance. If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters

Answer (score 2):

it cannot return, make sure your property is not empty

```
if (property != null)
{
    string[] splitData = sampleObject.property.Split(new char[] { ',' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. I cannot find any case where `string.Split()` returns `null`. I can get it to:

- Return an array containing one or more strings.
- Return an empty (zero length) array when the entries are removed with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.
- Throw a `NullReferenceException`, only when the string being split is `null`.

And those seem to be all of the possible outcomes. Lets run through some scenarios. First assume that we have:

```
public static void WriteArray(string[] values)
{
    Console.Write("[");
    foreach(var item in values)
    {
        Console.Write($"'{item}' ");
    }
    Console.Write("]");     
}

private static char[] comma = new char[] { ',' };
```

Then what do we get from e.g.

```
var source = "a,b,c";
WriteArray(source.Split(comma));
```

It is of course `['a' 'b' 'c' ]` - this is a success case. Now lets try to break it with bad inputs:

with `string source = null;` we get `Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

But other values do not break `string.Split`, they **return an array with one or more elements**:

```
"a,b,c":     ['a' 'b' 'c' ]
"a,b,c,":    ['a' 'b' 'c' '' ]
"a, b, c":   ['a' ' b' ' c' ]
"abc":       ['abc' ]
"a,b":       ['a' 'b' ]
"a":         ['a' ]
"":          ['' ]
" ":         [' ' ]
",":         ['' '' ]
",,":        ['' '' '' ]
"a,":        ['a' '' ]
```

You likely don't want these empty entries, so lets try those again with

`WriteArray(source.Split(comma, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`

And now we always get **an array with zero or more elements**:

```
"a,b,c":     ['a' 'b' 'c' ]
"a,b,c,":    ['a' 'b' 'c' ]
"a, b, c":   ['a' ' b' ' c' ]
"abc":       ['abc' ]
"a,b":       ['a' 'b' ]
"a":         ['a' ]
"":          []
" ":         [' ' ]
",":         []
",,":        []
"a,":        ['a']
```

NB: note that there's no string trimming of leading/trailing whitespace in either case - i.e. `a,b` does not give not identical output to `a, b`; But you can also use `StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries` to deal with that.

e.g.

```
    string source = "  a,, b,  c , ";
    WriteArray(source.Split(comma, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Displays

```
 ['a' 'b' 'c' ]
```